# How I can use MPI with shared memory?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I have two matrices that I want to multiply. I want to use MPI with shared memory, but do not understand how I can do this.

I do not understand what I should do in the preparatory stage. If the rank of my stream is 0, then I need to initialize the window, but what if the rank is not 0?

If a window is a shared memory location for all threads, then how can I synchronize its use?

Also, I don't understand how to parallelize the multiplication, I know the number of threads. How should the parameters of the cycle be changed?

I've put together a few examples piece by piece, but I doubt my code is correct. Please give me a hint. Thank you!

```
real :: a(5,6), b(6,4), result(5,6)

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror) ! get count of process 
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror) ! get if of current process

MPI_Win window;
MPI_Win_create(&result, sizeof(&result), sizeof(&result), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);

do i = 1,5
  result[i,j] = 0
  do j = 1,6 
   result[i,j] = result[i,j] + a[i,j] * b[j,i]
  end do
end do

MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

 if(process_Rank> 0)
    {
        // Push my value into the first integer in MPI process 0 window
        MPI_Accumulate(&result, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, window);
    }
 
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
 
    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        printf("[MPI process 0] result ");
   }
 
   MPI_Win_free(&window);
   MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: Your program is roughly 1/3 Fortran and 2/3 C. What language do you want?

Comment: @IanBush fortran